Flask-it keeps saying "Method Not Allowed"
I am using Flask to build my web. It keeps saying "Method Not Allowed" when I run app.py and navigate to the login page. I am not sure where I have gone wrong. Please help.
Here's my app.py:
from flask import Flask,render_template,url_for,redirect,session,request
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash


app = Flask(__name__)

# Configure SQL Alchemy
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'your_secret_key'
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = "sqlite:///users.db"
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS"] = False
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

# Database model
class Users(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(25),unique=True,nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(125),nullable=False)
    
    def set_password(self,password):
        self.password_hash = generate_password_hash(password)
        
    def check_password(self,password):
        return check_password_hash(self.password_hash,password)



# Routes

# Home

@app.route("/")
def index():
    if "username" in session:
        return redirect (url_for('home'))
    return render_template ('home.html')

# Login
@app.route("/login",methods=["GET","POST"])
def login():
 if request.method == 'POST':
    username = request.form["Username"]
    password = request.form["Password"]
    check_user = Users.query.filter_by(username=username).first()
    if check_user and check_user.check_password(password):
        session["username"] = username
        return redirect(url_for("dashboard"))
    else:
        return render_template ('login.html')

@app.route('/signup')
def signup():
    return render_template('signup.html')



if __name__ == '__main__':
    with app.app_context():
        db.create_all()
    app.run(debug=True)


here's my login.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Login</h2>
    <form action="/login" method="post" >
        <input type="text" name="Username" placeholder="Username" required>
        <input type="password" name="Password" placeholder="Password" required>
        <button type="submit">Login</button>
    </form>
    <p>Don't have an account? <a href="{{ url_for('signup') }}">Sign up</a></p>
</body>
</html>


I have tried so many ways, following some structure on YouTube. Nothing changes. Same error.

I suggest you revise code to be a  [mre].  It's a powerful debugging technique and it makes easier for you to help you.

Your login endpoint does not get the GET method. It is in POST method always according to your code. You can change it with this code and it can help:
@app.route("/login", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.form["Username"]
        password = request.form["Password"]
        check_user = Users.query.filter_by(username=username).first()
        if check_user and check_user.check_password(password):
            session["username"] = username
            return redirect(url_for("dashboard"))
        else:
            return render_template('login.html', error="Invalid credentials")
    else:
        return render_template('login.html')


No problem, happy to help

As you didn't include the traceback of you error, it's hard to conclude why you get the issue.
I did notice you didn't account for the GET method in your login function.
I suggest trying this revised version of the code:
@app.route("/login", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.form["Username"]
        password = request.form["Password"]
        check_user = Users.query.filter_by(username=username).first()
        if check_user and check_user.check_password(password):
            session["username"] = username
            return redirect(url_for("dashboard"))
        else:
            return render_template('login.html', error="Invalid username or password")
    else:
        # If the request method is GET, just render the login page
        return render_template('login.html')


I'd be glad if you could mark this answer as helpful :)
